# Android's ScrollView with Custom Swipe Events

Tags: android, scrollview, swipe, gesture

I am trying to implement swipe in `ScrollView` where if I swipe (fling) my finger down, the `ViewGroup` object will be refreshed (or simply call a method to create new item) and if I swipe my finger up, the `ViewGroup` object will be closed.

If you ever use Feedly, it does have swipe down to refresh and swipe up to close an article.

How could I implement this, is there a sample project out there that does this?

I understand the refresh part can be done with `SwipeRefreshLayout`, but `SwipeRefreshLayout` doesn't have swipe-up-to-close feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this example for implementing pull to refresh in ListView, GridView, WebView, Expandable ListView.

Use this example and make appropriate changes according to your Views.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

For handling swipe up, implement an `onTouchEvent` to handle the swipe up event.

Per [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was MOVE");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                    "of current screen element");
            return true;      
        default : 
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }      
}
```

Modify the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` case to close your article.

Comment: No. For that, you're going to need to do some slight modifications to handle the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`